# Trouble vertically aligning divs in list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am relatively new to css, sorry if this is real simple. I have been looking for a solution for more than an hour and cant seem to figure it out. I would like to vertically align timeline-panel and timeline-image. Note that h4 can have multiple lines, thus changing the height of timeline-panel.

Thanks
**edit**

I think I didnt explain myself correctly. Here is the page I am building. You can see it here on the about section. http://belyza.com/test437/
I added a top margin to the text for now, but that does not work with responsive theme when the text become multiple lines on smaller screens.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}
.timeline>li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 50px
}

.timeline>li .timeline-panel {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.timeline>li .timeline-image {
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  background-color: #E80B10;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #ff9600;
  text-align: center
}

.timeline>li .timeline-image h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 14px
}

.timeline .timeline-heading h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit
}

.timeline .timeline-heading h4.subheading {
  text-transform: none
}

.timeline .timeline-body>p,
.timeline .timeline-body>ul {
  margin-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li>
  
    <div class="timeline-image">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>test</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/uge02uLc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use flexbox you could set it up like this:

**EDIT**

Ok, so now that I see exactly what you are trying to do I've edited the code, I think this is what you're looking for.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline>li {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 50px
}

.timeline-panel-left:after,
.timeline-panel-right:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 80px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 80px);
}

.timeline-panel-left {
  text-align: right;
}

.timeline>li .timeline-panel {
  flex: 1 calc(50% - 80px);
  max-width: calc(50% - 80px);
}

.timeline>li .timeline-image {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E80B10;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #ff9600;
}

.timeline .timeline-heading h4 {
  margin: 0;
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li class="timeline-panel-left">
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>SERVICE DE RÉPARATION</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-image">
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="timeline-panel-right">
    <div class="timeline-image">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>DIAGNOSTIQUE</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using flex with align-items. I didnt know about this. I checked browser support and it seems pretty good. Hopefully it will continue to be in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure what the exact end objective looks like. I'm going to assume you want a circle above some text.

Since you're setting a width for `.timeline-image` you can go ahead and use `auto` for the left and right margins, one version is `margin: 0 auto;`. I then removed `position: absolute;`, `z-index: 100;` and `left: 50%;` from `.timeline-image`.

Using absolute positioning can do some weird things if you're not familiar with how it works.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline > li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.timeline-panel {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline-image {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E80B10;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #ff9600;
  text-align: center
}
.timeline-image h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 14px margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li>

    <div class="timeline-image">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>test</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you're looking for a single line of text to the left of the circle then you will need to re-arrange your markup a bit. Place `.timeline-image` after `.timeline-heading`. Set both of those to `display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;` and set `.timeline-heading` to `line-height: 60px;` (total height of `.timeline-image`).

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
.timeline > li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.timeline-panel {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline-heading {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 60px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.timeline-image {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E80B10;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 5px solid #ff9600;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.timeline-image h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 14px margin: 0;
  color: inherit
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>test</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="timeline-image"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`. Commented the properties which are not necessary.  `Display:flex` will not support lower versions of IE.

```css
.timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative
}
.timeline>li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    min-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.timeline>li .timeline-panel {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: initial;
}

.timeline>li .timeline-image {
    /* left: 50%; */
    /* margin-left: 15px; */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    /* z-index: 100; */
    background-color: #E80B10;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 5px solid #ff9600;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.timeline>li .timeline-image h4 {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  line-height: 14px
}

.timeline .timeline-heading h4 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: inherit
}

.timeline .timeline-heading h4.subheading {
  text-transform: none
}

.timeline .timeline-body>p,
.timeline .timeline-body>ul {
  margin-bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="timeline">
  <li>
  
    <div class="timeline-image">
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-panel">
      <div class="timeline-heading">
        <h4>test</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think I didnt explain myself correctly. Here is the page I am building. You can see it here on the about section. http://belyza.com/test437/
I added a top margin to the text for now, but that does not work with responsive theme when the text become multiple lines on smaller screens.